# Make a Libgdx Timer run once

Tags: java, timer, libgdx

My Goal: Make one script wait .5 seconds, run, make another script wait .5 seconds, run.

The problem I am running into is that Timer.instance().clear(); makes the run() method only run once, on it's own it runs more than once.  But, it also deletes Timer2 because it does not wait .5 seconds to run the code after the timer you scheduled (clear() removes all Timers/scheduled tasks).  So, it ends up deleting the the Timer2 after .5 seconds.

Edit: Made a dumb error, I was not recognizing how the method was being called.  I got it fixed :)

```
//Timer1
Timer.schedule(new Task(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // \/ removes both Timer1 and Timer2
        Timer.instance().clear();
    }
}, .5f);
//Timer2
Timer.schedule(new Task(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Timer.instance().clear();
    }
}, 1f);
```

Comment: What about a simple countdown variable?

Comment: @noone I might try that, but I have been having trouble with those lately.  Also, I edited the delay in Timer2, had some problems when transferring the code. (Changed from .5 to 1)

Comment: Hello, Timer.schedule(Timer.Task task, float delaySeconds)
Schedules a task on instance. This should run only once, what do you mean it runs more?

Comment: Make instance of timers: Timer timer1 = new Timer(); and Timer timer2 = new Timer(); then assign your schedules and code will run only once automatically. Like that: timer1.scheduleTask(....)

Comment: @aloupas Don't know how I didn't think of that earlier.  I found another way to do it, but thanks for helping in the future! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: "Make instance of timers: Timer timer1 = new Timer(); and Timer timer2 = new Timer(); then assign your schedules and code will run only once automatically. Like that: timer1.scheduleTask(....)" –  aloupas